# MyBatis - Map the records with difference in one column two individual objects

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I am facing difficulty with MyBatis when I try to get the metadata about tables, their columns, and constraints (MySQL database). I have the following query consisting of JOIN of four tables:

```
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME,
       T.TABLE_SCHEMA,
       T.CREATE_OPTIONS,
       T.TABLE_COMMENT,
       C.COLUMN_NAME,
       C.COLUMN_TYPE,
       C.COLUMN_DEFAULT,
       C.EXTRA,
       C.COLUMN_KEY,
       C.IS_NULLABLE,
       C.NUMERIC_PRECISION,
       C.NUMERIC_SCALE,
       C.ORDINAL_POSITION,
       C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
       TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
       TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
       TC.TABLE_SCHEMA,
       TC.TABLE_NAME AS CONSTRAINT_TABLE_NAME,
       TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
       KCU.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
         INNER JOIN
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
     ON T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
         AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
     ON TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
         AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA
         AND TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
         AND TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
         AND TC.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
         AND TC.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
         AND C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
         INNER JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU
                    ON KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA
                        AND KCU.TABLE_NAME = TC.TABLE_NAME
                        AND KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                        AND C.COLUMN_NAME = KCU.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND T.TABLE_NAME = 'order_items'
  AND TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
  AND C.TABLE_NAME = TC.TABLE_NAME
  AND TC.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY T.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

Now I have a situation where I have two identical tables in two different schemas:

| # | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA | CREATE_OPTIONS | TABLE_COMMENT | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_TYPE | COLUMN_DEFAULT | EXTRA | COLUMN_KEY | IS_NULLABLE | NUMERIC_PRECISION | NUMERIC_SCALE | ORDINAL_POSITION | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | CONSTRAINT_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | TABLE_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | COLUMN_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | order_items | unit_test_database_three |  |  | order_item_id3 | int |  | auto_increment | PRI | NO | 10 | 0 | 1 |  | PRIMARY | PRIMARY KEY | unit_test_database_three | order_items | unit_test_database_three | order_item_id3 |
| 2 | order_items | unit_test_database_three |  |  | order_id3 | int |  |  | MUL | NO | 10 | 0 | 2 |  | order_items_ibfk_1 | FOREIGN KEY | unit_test_database_three | order_items | unit_test_database_three | order_id3 |
| 3 | order_items | unit_test_database_three |  |  | product_id | int |  |  | MUL | NO | 10 | 0 | 3 |  | order_items_ibfk_2 | FOREIGN KEY | unit_test_database_three | order_items | unit_test_database_three | product_id |
| 4 | order_items | unit_test_database_two |  |  | order_item_id | int |  | auto_increment | PRI | NO | 10 | 0 | 1 |  | PRIMARY | PRIMARY KEY | unit_test_database_two | order_items | unit_test_database_two | order_item_id |
| 5 | order_items | unit_test_database_two |  |  | order_id | int |  |  | MUL | NO | 10 | 0 | 2 |  | order_items_ibfk_1 | FOREIGN KEY | unit_test_database_two | order_items | unit_test_database_two | order_id |
| 6 | order_items | unit_test_database_two |  |  | product_id | int |  |  | MUL | NO | 10 | 0 | 3 |  | order_items_ibfk_2 | FOREIGN KEY | unit_test_database_two | order_items | unit_test_database_two | product_id |

The MyBatis result map looks as follows:

```
<resultMap id="schemaMap" type="Schema">
        <constructor>
            <arg column="TABLE_SCHEMA" javaType="String"/>
        </constructor>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="tableConstraintMap" type="TableConstraint">
        <constructor>
            <arg column="CONSTRAINT_NAME" javaType="String"/>
            <arg column="CONSTRAINT_TYPE"
                 javaType="TableConstraint$ConstraintTypes"
                 typeHandler="ConstraintTypesTypeHandler"/>
            <arg column="CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA" resultMap="schemaMap"
                 javaType="Schema"/>
            <arg column="TABLE_SCHEMA" resultMap="schemaMap"
                 javaType="Schema"/>
            <arg column="TABLE_NAME" javaType="String"/>
        </constructor>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="columnMap" type="Column">
        <constructor>
            <arg column="COLUMN_NAME" javaType="String"/>
            <arg column="COLUMN_TYPE" javaType="String"/>
        </constructor>
        <result property="defaultValue" column="COLUMN_DEFAULT"/>
        <result property="extraDetail" column="EXTRA"/>
        <result property="key" column="COLUMN_KEY"/>
        <result property="nullable" column="IS_NULLABLE"
                typeHandler="BooleanTypeHandler"/>
        <result property="characterMaximumLength" column="CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH"/>
        <result property="numericPrecision" column="NUMERIC_PRECISION"/>
        <result property="numericScale" column="NUMERIC_SCALE"/>
        <result property="ordinalPosition" column="ORDINAL_POSITION"/>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="tableMap" type="Table">
        <constructor>
            <arg column="TABLE_NAME" javaType="String"/>
            <arg resultMap="schemaMap" javaType="Schema"/>
        </constructor>
        <result property="createOptions" column="CREATE_OPTIONS"/>
        <result property="comment" column="TABLE_COMMENT"/>
        <association property="columns" resultMap="columnMap"/>
        <association property="constraints" resultMap="tableConstraintMap"/>
    </resultMap>
```

My problem is that even though I got distinguishable results, MyBatis returns a single Table object that consists of all columns and constraints (based on equals methods) and a single Schema. I need to have two Table objects with the correct Schema, Columns and Constraints associated.

Does anyone know where I do have a mistake? If it is in query or results map? Thank you for any hints or help.

#### Update

As per comments, I tried to use the `idArgs` to the `Table` object's constructor, but it resulted in the creation of 6 Tables, each having one column. The tables should be created based on the combination of the TABLE_NAME and TABLE_SCHEMA columns.

Comment: It is distinguishable to you because you know what the 'keys' are. MyBatis needs `<id />` or `<idArg />` elements to identify objects. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#result-maps). If you have difficulty, please provide an executable demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues).

Comment: @ave If I use the <idArg>, it returns six instances instead of two. I need to tell MyBatis that the table object is determined by the schema and table name. Is there any way to combine these two values?

Comment: I wrote a quick [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/blob/master/so-76395586/) for you. I may not fully understand the design and had to make some guesses. Take a look at the comment I left in the XML mapper and if I'm off base, please copy/modify the project and share it on your GitHub repo.